# how to compare two pptx file using .net?

Tags: c#, .net, compare, powerpoint

I want to compare two .pptx files. After comparing I want to print the output like which slide has been changed?
Can anyone have any idea regarding this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename the PPTX file into *.zip file and then extract the content that will  contain the xml and image files so you can compare these files individually.

This is all you can do with dot net.

1. Rename *.pptx files to *.zip using `System.IO.File.Rename()`
2. Extract these *.zip files into separate directory using any compression library
3. extracted content will contain XML, Image and other files
4. Iterate over the sub directories and files and compare extracted content for both pptx files.

```html
\_rels\.rels
\docProps
\docProps\app.xml
\docProps\core.xml
\docProps\thumbnail.jpeg
\ppt
\ppt\_rels
\ppt\media
\ppt\notesMasters
\ppt\notesMasters\_rels
\ppt\notesMasters\notesMaster1.xml
\ppt\notesSlides
\ppt\notesSlides\_rels
\ppt\notesSlides\notesSlide1.xml
\ppt\notesSlides\notesSlide2.xml
\ppt\slideLayouts
\ppt\slideLayouts\_rels
\ppt\slideLayouts\slideLayout1.xml
\ppt\slideLayouts\slideLayout2.xml
\ppt\slideMasters
\ppt\slideMasters\_rels
\ppt\slideMasters\slideMaster1.xml
\ppt\slideMasters\slideMaster2.xml
\ppt\slides
\ppt\slides\_rels
\ppt\slides\slide1.xml
\ppt\slides\slide2.xml
\ppt\tags
\ppt\theme
\ppt\presentation.xml
\ppt\presProps.xml
\ppt\tableStyles.xml
\ppt\viewProps.xml
\[Content_Types].xml
```